# Auto Update Date & Timestamp in a specific cell irrespective of any data range (With or Without VBA)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, date, timestamp, auto-updates

Would anyone be able to help  me with this issue?

I have data based on the categories (as per spent) in specific columns & cells, i.e.,
`C4:C25`, `F4:F25`, `I4:I10`.

However, I want the "Updated date & Time stamp" in a specific cell, i.e. `I23` whenever I update any cell of the ranges mentioned above.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The following code was absolutely not tested. You will need to do the
necessary research to fix up my errors.

```
Function InRange(Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range) As Boolean
' returns True if Range1 is within Range2
Dim InterSectRange As Range
Set InterSectRange = Application.Intersect(Range1, Range2)
InRange = Not InterSectRange Is Nothing
Set InterSectRange = Nothing
End Function

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Set Range1 = Range("C4:C25")
  Set Range2 = Range("F4:F25")
  Set Range3 = Range("I4:I10")
  If InRange(Target.Address, Range1) OR InRange(Target.Address, Range2) OR InRange(Target.Address, Range3) Then
    Range("I23").Value = Now
  End If
End Sub
```